# how can sed match pattern delete line plus one and insert diferent file

Tags: sed

I believe i'm pretty close but there is 1 command missing..

i have file1.txt

```
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
dddddddddddddddddd
id="8" efwef
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
cccccccccccccccccccc
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

file2.txt

```
123

123
```

what i need is :

```
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
dddddddddddddddddd
123

123
cccccccccccccccccccc
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

explained: find pattern (id="8")
delete pattern line +1
insert into file1.txt content of file2.txt

i got this sed command

```
sed -e '/id="8"/,+1{' -e 'r /tmp/file2.txt' -e 'd' -e '}' -i /tmp/file1.txt
```

it does all i need ... except it inserts file2.txt twice...

probably because the `,+1` but i tryed several combos but can't get to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to specify the next line via an address range, try using `N` to pull it into the pattern space before the `d`:

```
$ sed -e '/id="8"/{r file2.txt' -e 'N;d;}' file1.txt
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
dddddddddddddddddd
123

123
cccccccccccccccccccc
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: strangely it does no change the file ...
i added a >/tmp/newfile.txt to be sure and it is equal to file 1...no change

Comment: what the ^means ? i removed it and it seems to work fine

Comment: @LcrossPortugal the `^` anchors the regex to the start of the line (to prevent false matches elsewhere in a line) - if your input is not as shown in your question (i.e. has other characters - such as leading spaces) then yes, remove it - I will do so in the answer as well

Comment: thanks ... indeed i had some text before the pattern...
marked as correct as it should ! thanks

Comment: Just a small detail .. it doesn't put in new line 
123cccccccccccccccccccc
any tricks for that

Comment: @LcrossPortugal perhaps that's because your `file2.txt` is unterminated?

Comment: unterminated?? didn't get that....
file was created with a sed printout to file